# $L^p$ closed in $L^1$

Tags: lp-spaces

Let (X, M, $\mu$) be a finite measure space.
Show the whole of $L^p(d \mu )$ is closed in $L^1(d\mu)$ iff $\exists C>0$ such that $||f||_{L^p}\le C\cdot||f||_{L^1}$ for all $f\in L^p(d\mu)$

$\Leftarrow$ is easy to show, as any sequence $\{f_n\}\subset L^p\cap L^1$ is cauchy in $L^1$ implies it being cauchy in $L^p$

This is a question on an analysis qualifying exam I've been looking at.  I am a little uncomfortable showing the other direction.  Does anyone have any hints?  I understand that this would come about iff (X,M,$d\mu$) is finite dimensional, but this question is supposed to be answered without looking into that information.

$L^p(d\mu)\hookrightarrow L^1(d\mu)$ since this is a finite measure space.

Convergence in $L^1$ is equivalent to convergence $\mu$-a.e. and convergence of the norm values (i.e. $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ iff $f_n\rightarrow f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $||f_n||_{L^1}\rightarrow||f||_{L^1}$)  I feel like this can be useful for showing the other direction, but am curious if someone can show a good clean way to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is show that if it is *not true* that $\|f\|_{p} \le C \|f\|_1$, then you could form a sequence that converges in $L^1$ but not $L^p$.

Comment: The negation would be that there exists an $f \in L^p$ s.t. $\forall C > 0$  we have $\|f\|_{p} > C \|f\|_1$ If we take the sequence given by $f_n(x) = f/n$ then this sequence converges to zero in $L^1$ but the norm is unbounded in $L^p$?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what $f$ could there exist s.t.  $\forall C > 0$  we have $\|f\|_{p} > C \|f\|_1$  .

Comment: @Monolite Your quantifiers are reversed: For every $C > 0$, you can find $f$ such that $\|f\|_p > C \|f\|_1$.

Answer (score 0):

If for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an $f_k$ s.t $\Vert f_k \Vert_1 < 2^{-k}\Vert f_k \Vert_p$, then on dividing both sides by $\Vert f_k \Vert_p$, we may assume that there exists $g_k$ s.t $\Vert g_k \Vert_p = 1$ but $\Vert g_k \Vert_1 < 2^{-k}$. Thus 
$$ \sum_{1}^{\infty} g_k $$ 
Is in $L^1$ but not in $L^p$